# Proof of (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra)

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof of (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), they take unitary $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$, $d = deg(P) = 2^nq$ with $q$ odd and $d \geq 1$. They went to show by induction on $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $P$ admits at least one root in $\mathbb{C}$. for this they are said :

> *"there exists an extension of field $\mathbb{K}$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and $x_1,..., x_d\in \mathbb{K}$ such that $P = {\prod_{i=1}^{d}(X—x_i)}$. For all $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and for $1 \leq i < j \leq d$, we set $y_{ij}(c) = x_i+ x_j + cx_ix_j$ and $Q = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq d}(X-y_{i,j}(c))$. **Then coefficients of $Q$ are symmetric polynomials with real coefficients in the $x_i$**"*

But I did not understand why we have the sentence written in large ie "Then coefficients of $Q$ are symmetric polynomials with real coefficients in the $x_i$". An idea please.

Comment: "But I did not understand" - have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) on symmetric polynomials, with examples, then it will be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rename the numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_d$; let us call them $y_1,\ldots,y_d$. These are the **same** numbers as before; only their order has changed (maybe). Therefore$$\prod_{i=1}^d(X-x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^d(X-y_i).$$But since we have twice the same polynomial, then, in particular, we have twice the same coefficients. So, these coefficients do not change when we change the order of the numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_d$. But that's what being a symmetric polynomial *means*.

Answer (score 1):

There are three claims in the sentence you highlighted:

1. each coefficient of $Q$ is a polynomial in the $x_i$
2. this polynomial has real coefficients
3. this polynomial is symmetric

I think your only confusion is with claim 3, since the first two claims are pretty straightforward to see (all operations done when multiplying out the terms in $Q$ and collecting like terms are polynomial in nature, and likewise everything in sight is real-valued so there is no way to obtain things outside the real numbers as coefficients, since the real numbers form a field).

For claim three, we need to understand why permuting the $x_i$ leaves the polynomial unchanged. This ultimately follows from the commutativity of multiplication, since it doesn't matter which order we multiply the terms in $Q$.